# Simple node C addon for memory mapped file crashes node

Tags: c++, v8, mmap

My goal is to create a simple addon that opens a memory mapped file and gives node raw access to the buffer. The memory mapped file already exists so I don't need to create a new file -- error will be thrown if file not already created (by another process).

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <nan.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace v8;

void get_shm(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo <v8::Value> &info) {
    if (info.Length() != 1) {
        return Nan::ThrowTypeError("Wrong number of arguments. You must specify size of mapped file!");
    }

    if (!info[0]->IsNumber()) {
        return Nan::ThrowTypeError("Bad argument. Size of mapped file must be a number!");
    }

    int len = info[0]->Uint32Value();

    HANDLE h = OpenFileMappingA(FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ, 1, "Global\\_GB_SharedMemory_Read");
    if (h == NULL) {
        Nan::ThrowTypeError("Couldn't open memory mapped file");
    }

    char *buf = (char *) MapViewOfFile(h, FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, len);

    Nan::MaybeLocal<Object> jsbuf = Nan::NewBuffer(buf, len);
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(jsbuf.ToLocalChecked());
}

void Init(v8::Local <v8::Object> exports) {
    exports->Set(Nan::New("get_shm").ToLocalChecked(), 
       Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(get_shm)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(addon_shm, Init)
```

Unfortunately node is crashing (presumably due to access violation) at some point after the NewBuffer is returned. It doesn't crash immediately but some unpredictable time after.

I'm not attempting to read/write from the buffer in Javascript. The only line using the add on is this:

```
const buf=shm.get_shm(10);
```

Mapped file created by the other process is bigger than 10.

If I use malloc to create the buffer, problem doesn't occur.

If I just call get_shm(10) without storing the result, problem doesn't occur.

Struggling to understand the issue...

Comment: Your code is no valid C but it is C++. C and C++ are different languages. Please use correct language tag.

Comment: Don't spam tags and get the text right. You used a very different language! And this is not related to JS either.

Comment: @olaf This _does_ have to do with JS as it's the V8 javascript engine.

Comment: @Qix: Not the language, but the framework. But I'm fine with tagging the engine. I was not aware which one it was and a bit upset by another obviously wrongly tagged C++ question, so I left the node.js.